# "being wined and dined" -- singular?

Tags: verb-agreement, numbers

I want to say, "He loves being wined and dined, and he's not above demanding it." I don't know whether *being* can be treated as the referent of *it*, or I must take the whole verb phrase as a plural. I realize that could use *them*, but for apparently brain-stem reasons I am unable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Being* is just one thing, not two.

*Being wined* on the one hand and *being dined* on the other might just might be two things (though I doubt it) but *being wined and dined* is definitely just one thing alone.

Use *it*.

Comment: I don't understand the explanation well enough that it would be transferable to other cases. For example, "My dog hates being washed and trimmed and he fusses with both." How do I interpret your statement that "being is just one thing, not two" in this context?

Answer (score 2):

It **is** singular. The expression is an idiom (seldom used in the literal sense) meaning being entertained lavishly.

Sorry about there being neither real wine nor a real dinner, though there could be.

HTH.